# Ftp via php - connection reset

Tags: php, ftp

I have some problem. I bought virtual server and I can't configured all options in php.ini file. There is time execution limit for php scripts. So I transferred upload script to other server where I have permission to php.ini. I changed `set_time_limit, upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, max_input_time, max_execution_time` and then I created a ftp connection with my virtual server for file transfer. However when 2MB is passed then the connection is reset. Is any other option in server configuration files which I can change to repair this bug?

Comment: you can configure some ini options at run time. but i's suggest un-buying the virtual server that doesnt let you have your own php.ini

Comment: I can't do it now. I must solve this problem so I transferred upload.php file to other sever and created ftp connection to avoid restrictions of my current server configuration

Comment: I don't think about ftp_pasv(). This may resolve problem? If this is problem of ftp connection mode why always script is reset when 2MB was transferred?

Answer (score 0):

You can set these values in your .htaccess file, with varied results on shared hosting.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
php_value post_max_size 50M
```

See, http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-override-php-configuration-settings/

Comment: I set maximum values and other random values in php.ini file and I called phpinfo() to see that options are correctly added. Everything is set good so I don't need set it in htaccess

Comment: http://help.ovh.co.uk/ConfigPhp
I have hosting in ovh. There are options that I can set